# Ubuntu failing to install linux-image-5.4.0-52-generic during install of Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

```
installed linux-image-5.4.0-52-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exist status 1
```

This is occurring during installation.

Things to note:

- this is a dual boot system, windows is already installed
- the ubuntu installation consists of a 100mb `/boot` partition and the rest of the space is going to an encrypted partition mounted to `/`

Comment: That looks a summary of the error, which is not enough information to help, sorry. Exit Status 1 simply means that "something went wrong" with some subprocess. Depending upon the install, there might be hundreds, even thousands of such subprocesses. We need to see the complete, original error message. If you were installing, look in /var/log/install of your installed system for the casper.log and syslog files. One of those should have the real error message.

Comment: My own boot takes up 135MB, so perhaps you might simply be out of space in your 100MB partition.

Comment: 100MB is not enough space for a `/boot` partition these days.  Make it 250MB or 500MB if you can afford it.

Comment: Thanks, upped the `/boot` partition to 500MB and seems everything is good now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by [user535733](https://askubuntu.com/users/19626/user535733) and [Nmath](https://askubuntu.com/users/953371/nmath) 100MB was not large enough for the `/boot` parition.